# Responsive popup div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am trying to create a popup div on div hover for my website like homeaway website's top right corner image section.

I tried the following example.

```js
var moveLeft = 0;
var moveDown = 0;
$('a.popper').hover(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).show();
    moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
    moveDown = $(target).outerHeight();
}, function () {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    if (!($("a.popper").hasClass("show"))) {
        $(target).hide();
    }
});
$('a.popper').mousemove(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
    maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
    windowLeft = $(window).width() - 10;
    windowRight = 0;
    /*maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 10);*/
    maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + 100);
    if (maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight) {
        leftD = maxLeft;
    }
    topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
    maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 40);
    windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
    maxTop = topD;
    windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
    if (maxBottom > windowBottom) {
        topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 10;
    } else if (maxTop < windowTop) {
        topD = windowTop + 25;
    }
 //$(target).css('top', 65).css('left', 1030);
   $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);
});
$('a.popper').click(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    if (!($(this).hasClass("show"))) {
        $(target).show();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
.popbox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFAFF;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #77C5ED;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
    right:5px;
    top: 10053px;
}
.popbox h2 {
    background-color: #4D4F53;
    color: #E3E5DD;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1" style="padding:0;"><img  />Text</a>
<div id="pop1" class="popbox">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus faucibus mauris sed elit imperdiet pharetra. 

  Suspendisse semper diam eleifend, vehicula arcu eget, porttitor mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eget ultrices erat. 

  In a neque velit. Vivamus sagittis lacinia erat a tristique. Vivamus et libero erat.
</div>
```

My JS FIDDLE [link](http://jsfiddle.net/42mxh65j/2/)

What I want to achieve is,

Wherever the text located, the popup div should display under the text. But I am unable to move forward.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want that popup will show below the text in **any case**?

Comment: So it's not **any case**, but only `If window shrinks`. For example if the link in the example is floating right?

Comment: @MoshFeu Sorry I removed my previous comment. In any case, wherever the text located, the popup box should appear below.

Comment: Are you mean like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/D8h38.png

Comment: If it's not the case, please update your question so I can update my answer.

Comment: @MoshFeu Question updated.

Comment: Do you mean (in your example) that the link should be in the right corner of the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97290/discussion-between-gunaseelan-and-mosh-feu).

Comment: I saw that you left the char's room. Did you get on with it?

Comment: @MoshFeu I am working on it. I will update once completed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I was covered all of your requirements.

```js
var moveLeft = 0;
var moveDown = 0;
$('a.popper').hover(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    $(target).show();
    moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
    moveDown = $(target).outerHeight();
}, function () {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    if (!($("a.popper").hasClass("show"))) {
        $(target).hide();
    }
});
$('a.popper').mousemove(function (e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var target = '#' + (elem.attr('data-popbox'));
    leftD = e.pageX;// + parseInt(moveLeft);
    maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
    windowLeft = $(window).width() - 10;
    windowRight = 0;
    /*maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 10);*/
    maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + 100);
    if (maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight) {
        leftD = maxLeft;
    }
    topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
    maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 40);
    windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
    maxTop = topD;
    windowTop = elem.offset().top + elem.outerHeight(true);
    if (maxBottom > windowBottom) {
        topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 10;
        leftD += 20;
    } else if (maxTop < windowTop) {
        topD = windowTop + 10;
    }
 //$(target).css('top', 65).css('left', 1030);
   $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);
});
$('a.popper').click(function (e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
    if (!($(this).hasClass("show"))) {
        $(target).show();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
.popbox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFAFF;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #77C5ED;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(164, 164, 164, 1);
    right:5px;
    top: 10053px;
}
.popbox h2 {
    background-color: #4D4F53;
    color: #E3E5DD;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -10px 0px 8px -10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="popper" data-popbox="pop1" style="padding:0;"><img  />Text</a>
<div id="pop1" class="popbox">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus faucibus mauris sed elit imperdiet pharetra. 

  Suspendisse semper diam eleifend, vehicula arcu eget, porttitor mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eget ultrices erat. 

  In a neque velit. Vivamus sagittis lacinia erat a tristique. Vivamus et libero erat.
</div>
```